# How Do I Create Multi-File C++ Projects

Tags: c++, codeblocks, header-files

I know there are similar questions here, but I can't find an answer. I'm using code::blocks on a windows 10, GNU compiler, I believe. I have a three files in a project, (I'm trying to make a binary to base ten converter, still a beginner, so the code is open to suggestion too,) main.cpp and functions.cpp in a the sources folder, and functions.h in the header file. I can't figure out how to link them correctly, what I've been trying is this:
In main.cpp,

```
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    long long number_In_Binary;
    cout << "Please enter a binary number: ";
    cin >> number_In_Binary;
    cout << number_In_Binary << " in decimal is " << 
    binaryToBaseTen(number_In_Binary) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

in functions.cpp,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

int binaryToBaseTen(long long binaryNum){

    int baseTen = 0;
    int iterations = 0;
 while (binaryNum > 0){
        int binaryDigit = binaryNum % 10;
        if (binaryDigit == 1){
            baseTen += pow(2.0, iterations);
       };
       iterations ++;
       binaryNum /= 10;
    };
    return baseTen;

};
```

and functions.h,

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

using namespace std;
int binaryToBaseTen(long long binaryNum);


#endif // FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

so again, the code's awful because I'm still learning the ropes, but there's only one function, so it doesn't seem like it would be so difficult to link in the header file. It works if I just replace main.cpp's "#include "functions.h"" with "#include "functions.cpp"" but I want to learn to use header files. The error the code above gives me is

> "undefined reference to 'binaryToBaseTen(long long)'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't use HTML/CSS/JS snippets for C++ questions (or anything else besides HTML/CSS/JS).

Comment: I assume the problem is `functions.cpp` is not part of your project but I don't use Code::Blocks so I can't help with the IDE. Is there an "Add file to project" menu item or similar?

Comment: Is it correct to assume you have all those files open in Code::Blocks? If you right-click the "functions.cpp" tab, is there a "Add file to active project" option? A "Remove file from project option"? If you see neither, I suppose the `File` menu's options regarding projects (e.g. "Save project as") are inactive?

Comment: Also, do you mind if I trim your code down to a more minimal example? There is more noise there than is necessary (but not too bad for a first try).

Comment: Yeah, it's cool to trim it down. I just wanted to have the full context in case the problem wasn't what I thought it was. Also, all of the files are open in the same project. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

*The asker did not provide clarifications, so I don't know how applicable this answer will be. However, it might be useful to future readers with the same question.* I currently use Code::Blocks version 16.01; details (such as the placement of menu options) may vary in other versions.

## Make sure you have a project open

A official "project" is what tells Code::Blocks to link multiple translation units into a single executable. So if only one file is being compiled, the first thing to check is that you have actually opened a project, not just added files to a workspace.
Code::Blocks can be a little confusing in this regard since you can open a file without opening a project.

One way to see if you have a project open is to go to the `File` menu. If no projects are open, the `Save project as...` and `Close project` entries will be disabled. If these entries are disabled, go to the `New >` entry then select `Project...` to create a new project.

## Make sure you have *one* project open

Another potential source of confusion is that Code:Blocks allows you to have multiple projects open at once. While this is not a bad thing, it adds complexity. For the sake of simplicity while resolving this issue, close all the projects except one.

If you're not sure how many projects you have open, you can close all of them (`File` menu -> `Close all projects`) then open the one that should have the files you want to compile (`File` menu -> `Recent projects` might allow you to do this quickly).

## Make sure the files are in the project

Once you have a single project open, look at the files. You can have a file open yet not have it in the project.

Right-click each file. This can be done in the tree view of the project or in the tab for that file in the editor pane. If you get an option to `Remove file from project` then it is in the project. On the other hand, if you see `Add file to active project` then the file is not yet in the project – select that option to add it.

## Make sure the files are in build targets

When you add files to your project, you are asked which build targets it should be associated with. (By default, your build targets are "debug" and "release".) I don't know why this option exists, nor do I know why the default (in my version of Code::Blocks) is to add it to no targets. Whenever I add a file to a project, I intend for it to belong to all build targets. I could rant, but let's move on to what to do.

Right-click each file and select `Properties...`. This can be done in the tree view of the project or in the tab for that file in the editor pane. Switch to the `Build` tab. If the file is in the project, this tab lets you opt to compile and link the file (selected by default, which is good), and lets you select which targets it belongs to. Make sure all of the targets are selected.

*If you find the properties window intimidating, an alternative approach is to remove the file from the project, then re-add it. Just make sure you select all build targets when given the option to do so.*

## Success?

That's all I can think of for now. I suppose the most likely scenario is that the files are in the project but not in the build targets. The other possibilities are points of potential confusion, but less easy to stumble into if you are under the impression that you "have three files in a project", as the OP is.

Comment: This answer was super helpful (and impressively well-organized), and it turns out my files weren't in the build targets. I went back and added them to the build target, and it worked like a charm. What a silly sausage I am! Anyway, thank you so much for your help, and may the programming gods smile upon you until the very last semicolon you type.